# How to loop through the folder with files?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I loop through the folder that has subfolder and retrieve all files with extension '.element.ts' ?

```
       const fs = require('fs'); 
       const filesDir = fs.readdirSync('packages/web-components/src');

       // the json result that will be generated
       let content = []; 

       files.forEach(file => {
         if (fileName === '???') 
           content.push(file);
       });
```

Comment: Your variable names don't match. `files` should be `filesDir`, and `fileName` should be `file`.

Comment: Where are you checking if the extension is `.element.ts`? Do you know about the `.endsWith()` method?

Comment: no, I didn't know about this method, I will try

Answer (score 1):

```
const fs=require('fs');

function getAllFiles (dir, allFilesList = []){
    const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
    files.map(file => {
      const name = dir + '/' + file;
      if (fs.statSync(name).isDirectory()) { // check if subdirectory is present
        getAllFiles(name, allFilesList);     // do recursive execution for subdirectory
      } else {
          allFilesList.push(name);           // push filename into the array
      }
    })
    
    return allFilesList;
}

const allFiles = getAllFiles('./testfolder');
const fileEndsWith = allFiles.filter(file => file.endsWith('.element.ts'))

console.log(fileEndsWith);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way: use [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) package.

```
const glob = require("glob");
const pattern = "packages/web-components/src/*.element.ts"
const elementTsFilenames = glob.sync(pattern);
```

Manual way:

```
const dir = "packages/web-components/src";
const extension = ".element.ts";
const elementTsFilenames = fs.readdirSync(dir).filter(fn => fn.endsWith(extension));
```

This is easy enough that the manual way is as easy or easier; if you have more complex requirements (e.g. recursively searching subdirectories), a library approach is nice.

Comment: Thank you for you solution sketch. In the src folder I have subfolders with the names of components, I guess second way is fitting my case better? Or for the first case, can I transform const pattern to  "packages/web-components/src/*/*.element.ts"

Comment: `"packages/web-components/src/*/*.element.ts"` for the `.element.ts` files in direct subfolders; `"packages/web-components/src/**/*.element.ts"` to search in any subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you how to recursively get all the files in a directory (even those located in a subdirectory).

To do this, we need to create a recursive function that can call itself when dealing with sub-directories. And we also need the function to go through each of the sub-directories and add any new files it encounters. Then we also need to check if the filename contains a specific string. When the function is finished , it should return an array with all the files it encountered.

Here's what the recursive function looks like:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

const getAllFiles = function(dirPath, extension, arrayOfFiles) {
  files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);

  arrayOfFiles = arrayOfFiles || [];

  files.forEach(function(file) {
    if (fs.statSync(dirPath + "/" + file).isDirectory()) {
      arrayOfFiles = getAllFiles(dirPath + "/" + file, arrayOfFiles);
    } else if (file.endsWith(extension)){
      arrayOfFiles.push(path.join(__dirname, dirPath, "/", file));
    }
  });

  return arrayOfFiles;
}
```

> First, we `require()` the Node.js `path` module. Since this is
> included with Node.js, you don't need to install anything for it to
> work. This module will help us easily create full file paths for our
> files.
>
> The `getAllFiles` variable holds the recursive function that will go
> through each subdirectory and return an array of filenames. It takes a
> directory file path, a specified character and an optional arrayOfFiles as arguments.
>
> Inside the `getAllFiles` function, we first use the `readdirSync()`
> function to get all of the files and directories inside the given
> dirPath supplied to the function.
>
> Then, we create an `arrayOfFiles` that will hold all the filenames
> that will be returned when the function is done running.
>
> Next, we loop over each item (file or directory) found by the
> `readdirSync()` function. If the item is a directory, we have the
> function recursively call itself to get all of the files and
> sub-directories inside the given directory.
>
> And if the item is a file, we simply append the file path to the
> `arrayOfFiles` array. (When the end of the file name is confirmed to
> contain characters)
>
> When the `forEach` loop has finished, we return the `arrayOfFiles`
> array.

Here is how you use the function in your code:

```
const result = getAllFiles("packages/web-components/src", ".element.ts");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need an npm package for this: It's not too hard to walk the file system using an async iterator and filter the results based on something like a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Another bonus of an [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) technique is that it doesn't block your thread while it iterates the files (other work can be done in between each result while it's searching), especially if you have a lot of sub-directories/files to search through.

If you want to reduce your project's dependencies, you can do something like this:

`example.mjs`:

```js
import * as path from 'node:path';
import {readdir} from 'node:fs/promises';

/** Search all subdirectories, yielding matching file entries */
export async function* findFiles (dir, regexpFilter) {
  for (const entry of await readdir(dir, {withFileTypes: true})) {
    const fPath = path.resolve(dir, entry.name);
    if (entry.isDirectory()) {
      yield* findFiles(fPath, regexpFilter);
      continue;
    }
    if (regexpFilter && !regexpFilter.test(entry.name)) continue;
    yield Object.assign(entry, {path: fPath});
  }
}

async function main () {
  const dir = 'packages/web-components/src';
  
  // Regular expression which means: ends with '.element.ts'
  const filter = /\.element\.ts$/;

  for await (const entry of findFiles(dir, filter)) {
    //                                     ^^^^^^
    // If you don't include a filter argument, then all files will be iterated

    console.log(entry.name); // just the file name
    console.log(entry.path); // the full file path
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: You don't _need_ a package — someone obviously wrote that library code without the benefit of itself — but it sure is convenient :P